# Javascript function apparently not firing

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have an `<iframe>` control on my page and I want to change it's target url (the url of the page displayed in the iframe) by a click on a hyperlink. The problem is that the iframe doesn't update on the click. I'm pretty sure I'm missing something, but I don't know what:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var source = document.getElementById("CurrentlySelected")
function change(u) {
    if (source.getAttribute("src") != u) {
        source.setAttribute("src", u);
        document.location.reload(true);
    }
}
</script>

<ul>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="change('http://www.somewebsite.com');">Website 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="change('http://www.thiswebsite.net');">Website 2</a></li>
</ul>

<iframe id="CurrentlySelected" width="800px" height="600px" src="http://www.somewebsite.com"></iframe>
```

JS is not my forte, but I don't see a problem here... any ideas?

Another problem is that the background of the iframe isn't taking the same color of the website linked in its src attribute...

**EDIT**
The issue with the background color of the website in the iframe seems to be an issue with Google Chrome, anyone know about a fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write `document.location.reload(true)`, you are refreshing the *parent* page, resetting the `<iframe>` to point to the original URL.
Remove that line; setting the `src` attribute will already reload the frame.

Also, you're calling `document.getElementById` before the `<iframe>` element exists; you should move the `<script>` block after the `<iframe>`.

Comment: Ah sweet, right on the money with the url switching :) any idea about the iframe's background color?

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="change('http://www.somewebsite.com');">Website 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="change('http://www.thiswebsite.net');">Website 2</a></li>
</ul>

<iframe id="CurrentlySelected" width="800px" height="600px" src="http://www.somewebsite.com"></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
// now iframe is available...
var source = document.getElementById("CurrentlySelected")
function change(u) {
    if (source.getAttribute("src") != u) {
        source.setAttribute("src", u);
        // NOT NEEDED: document.location.reload(true);
    }
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem your `document.location.reload(true);`?  If you're changing the iframe's URL but then reloading the page that contains the iframe, the iframe's URL will be set back to the state of what's in the host page's HTML.